# How to turn off "Low resolution aspect ratios"

Tags: unity-game-engine

It's greyed out and I can't turn it off. I think it is a reason why game view looks different than scene. Does anyone know how to turn it off

[image: photo with problem]

Answer (score 0):

It looks blocky because you're zoomed in 5x in the Game View.

The "Low Resolutions Aspect Ratios" checkbox is only enabled on Retina or Hi-DPI screens.

Comment: So what should I do

Comment: Move the "Scale" slider to 1x

Comment: I did it , but nothing change [photo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bnykOMNmYms9sgyCHbZUV3qvgBkKpNVP/view?usp=sharing)